# Failed low-quality queue test, looked OK to me

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27323910

While I'm not an expert in the area, the answer seems legitimate.
It suggests using a package for doing what the OP requests. Why was it deleted? Is there a panel where I can retrieve this information autonomously?

Comment: That answer linked to a module written by answer's author, without disclosing affiliation. It was deleted as spam. Maybe there were more instances of this behaviour. On the LQP queue, one should be looking out for these things.

Comment: I see. I must confess that I missed the affiliation. Just to clarify, if the author had disclosed affiliation, would have it been OK?
Anyway, I can accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: On its own, if the affiliation was disclosed, it would have been OK. But if I encountered it on the LQP queue I'd be suspicious, and try to look for more details (e.g. if there are more posts engaged in self-promotion). In the process it would have been possible to discover the audit nature of the review.